# PHP: Undefined index in $_POST

Tags: php, html

I am using forms select. I just want to check what user selects by echo-ing the result on the same page so I kept the action="". But its showing error undefined index slct. Can any one please help me

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="slct">
<option value="yes" selected="selected"> yes </option>
<option value="no"> no </option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php 
$tofd = $_POST["slct"];
echo $tofd; 
?>
```

Why its showing the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: slct in C:\wamp\www\Univ Assignment\Untitled-4.php on line 21
```

Comment: That will display value if form is submitted. btw good luck for your assignment. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

You should use button type submit NOT button

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

And then test IT like

```
echo (isset($_POST['slct']))? $_POST['slct'] : 'Variable undefined..';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if its exist first

Example :

```
$tofd = isset($_POST["slct"]) ? $_POST["slct"] : null ;
```

Example 2 Using a function

```
function __POST($var)
{
    return  isset($_POST[$var]) ? $_POST[$var] : null ;
}

$tofd = __POST("slct");
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same page, initaially, `$_POST` would be empty because the user has not posted anything. So you have to handle that.

```
if(isset($_POST["slct"]))
    $tofd = $_POST["slct"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["slct"])){
  $tofd = $_POST["slct"];
  echo $tofd; }
?>
```